# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable from a beginner

Tags: python-3.6

I have a piece of code giving me an error on the following line

Reset cart is a function shown below.
Can someone please tell me how I can fix this?

```
[pre_s, s, pre_a, a, x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot] = reset_cart(beta)    # reset the cart pole to initial state
```

> TypeError:
>   'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
[pre_s, s, pre_a, a, x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot] = reset_cart(beta)
def reset_cart(beta):
pre_s=1
s=1
pre_a=-1  
a=-1   


x = 0
x_dot = 0
theta = 0
theta_dot = 0.01
```

Comment: Where is the return statement? If you are expecting the values to be returned they must explicitly be returned. Also using a list, hmm I think you need a tuple here on the return statement and you should remove the square brackets that is a syntax error. Additionally, you are calling a function before it is defined which means python, being interpreted, won't know about it.

Comment: put your code and errors with proper format tags

Comment: Hello Sir, thank you so much for your intake but i am completely new to coding and python, so i pretty much do not understand most of the things you asking me to do. Should I replace the brackets by something else (maybe parentheses ).

Comment: Also should the function come before the place its called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a key part of your `reset_cart` function: The return.

Right now, when your `reset_cart` function finishes, all those variables it just set disappear because they were never assigned values outside of the function. The main way to get values from a function to wherever else you want to use them is to return them with the return statement.

In this case, you're trying to set those 8 elements to the values given in the function, so return a list that holds those 8 elements:

```
def reset_cart(beta):

    pre_s=1
    s=1
    pre_a=-1  #the agent is taking no action
    a=-1

    x = 0
    x_dot = 0
    theta = 0
    theta_dot = 0.01
    return [pre_s, s, pre_a, a, x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot]
```

For more information on returning variables and on variable scopes, see:

[What is the purpose of the Return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful.